# How would I exclude them from the 2nd query?

Tags: if-statement, mysqli, foreach, exists

I commented out this section to check what we got so far:

```
        echo "
    <div class='formTitle' style='position: relative; text-align: center; margin-top: 20px'>Medals</div>
    <table class='profileTable' id='medalTable' style='border-top-width: 0px'>
";
$mID = $_GET['mID'];
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ".$dbprefix."clanawards_members WHERE maa_member_id = '$mID'");
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //RETRIEVE ALL COLUMN NAMES then run a foreach to run each one through the next query
        foreach($row as $key => $val) {
            // $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ".$dbprefix."clanawards WHERE EXISTS name = '$key'");
                // while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                // $awardName = $row['name'];
                //  $description = $row['description'];
                    echo "
                        <tr><td class='main' align='center'>$key<br>$awardName</td></tr>    
                    ";
                //}
        }
    }
echo "</table>";
```

this gave me the table columns lists i was looking for but we i added the commented section back in it gives me this:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in PREVIOUSFOLDERS/include/profile/_medals.php on line 34

Which is the while clause on the second query... I think it has to do with the fact that EXISTS is in the wrong location or is not working the way i want it to altogether but I never used EXISTS before.

The columns or $keys contain 3 column names that won't be in the next database. How would I exclude them from the 2nd query?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understanding this, but I think this is what you want:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
    $result = $mysqli->query(...);
  }
}
```

Inside the loop, `$key` will be the column name, and `$val` will be that column's value for that row.

I'm not sure whether the "Award" is the column name or the actual cell value, but you can replace either `$key` or `$val` with `$Award` (although it should be `$award` if you want to be consistent...  `:)` )

Comment: ok did a little editing how would i add the if exists the the second query?